# Why firebase phone number authentication doesn't not work with the number that is in the phone?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing an app with Flutter,
And when authenticating the User (I use firebase auth)
Normally I receive an SMS validation code on my phone

The problem that this code is not valid when I try it. On the other hand, if I use another number (from another phone not the one I use with the application) this code is valid and passes without problem on my phone.

I tried with several devices and it's the same every time.

```
    void phonenumberauth(String PhoneNumber) async {
    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: PhoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        // Get.dialog(Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          Get.snackbar('Error', 'the provided phone number in not valid ');
        } else {
          Get.snackbar('Error', '${e.message}');
        }
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, int? resendToken) {
        this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
      },
    );
  }
```

```
Future<bool> verifyOTP(String otp) async {
    var credentials = await auth.signInWithCredential(
        PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verificationId: verificationId.value, smsCode: otp));
    return credentials.user != null ? true : false;
  }
```

```
Future<bool?> verifiyOTP(String otp) async {
    //CollectionReference usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    var isVerified = await Auth_controller.instance.verifyOTP(otp);
    String? userId = Auth_controller.instance.user?.uid;
    //var userDoc = await usersCollection.doc(userId).get();
    isVerified ? Get.offAll(SignupPhoneNumber()) : Get.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at these

1. Test the app with other phone numbers and carriers to see if it's just an issue with one number or a specific carrier.
2. Update Flutter, Firebase, and other related stuff to their latest versions. Note that you may be using a lower version than the one in pubspec.yaml, especially if you are using different packages. The current version is in the .lock file.
3. You might be hitting the SMS sending limit on Firebase Auth. Check the Firebase Console and see if you've reached the limit.

I can help more if you post the detailed error message.